# Running a webserver unikernel on RaspberryPi

Tags: web-server, server, performance

Is there anyone who have tried to install a webserver unikernel on a Raspberry?

In both cases, is it something possible and could one run an efficient webserver from it? What are your thoughts on something like this?

Comment: Ive thought about it. But Im not so satisfied with the performance of the Pi that I want to try and run VMs on it. Maybe, for static sites/pages. Thats a Pi issue though. Unikernels could be great for application specific technology, maybe performance could be increased with hardware specific kernels.

Comment: I don't think the other comment really understands the definition of unikernel. I'm looking into doing this, found your question, I know it is old.